# Question that does not need an answer

Tags: questions

I got teased by my daughter often so I said

> Why you like to tease me so much?

It wasn't a question since I did't expect her to answer, it was more like complaining. Is it ok to skip the word "do" after the word "why"?

Comment: In standard English?  No, you cannot drop the "do".  Whether you expected an answer or not does not affect the "do".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is: Nope, it isn't ok.

You need the auxillery verb to support the active verb, in this case the verb 'tease'. It contains certain nuances that make the sentence make sense. It isn't redundant as you could very well be wanting to ask "Why don't you tease me so much?" or "Why will you tease me so much?" etc.